# I want to take data from a form and store the information in firebase, but the data is not getting to my realtime database. Does anybody know why?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase account and an open project. I copied the snippet for the database and followed their read-write tutorial, but something still isn't right and I don't know what it is.

I know this question has been asked a couple times, but nothing has helped me figure out what's wrong.

```
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script type="module">

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("registerBtn");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
    btn.onclick = function () {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function () {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    function submitRegister() {
      alert("This is working");
      var discName = document.getElementById('discordName').value;
      var userEmail = document.getElementById('userEmail').value;
      var positionSelect = document.getElementById('debatePosition');
      var userPosition = positionSelect.options[positionSelect.selectedIndex].text;

      var debateTypeSelect = document.getElementById('debateType');
      var userDebateType = debateTypeSelect.options[debateTypeSelect.selectedIndex].text;

      const now = new Date();
      now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
      var userDT = document.getElementById('userDateTime').value = now.toISOString().slice(0, 16);

      if (discName == "" || userEmail == "" || positionSelect == "None" || userDebateType == "None") {
        alert("Plese select something for all the")
      } else {
        var data = {
          name: discName,
          email: userEmail,
          position: userPosition,
          type: userDebateType
        }
        var database = firebase.database();
        var ref = database.ref("users");
        ref.set(data);
      }
    }
  </script>
  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase-database.js"></script>
```

The config file only has the firebase code that they give you:

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/database";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCXfAcG9Ux2DuX38IHPbuxFok65uira_I8",
  authDomain: "debate-app-2305f.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://debate-app-2305f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "debate-app-2305f",
  storageBucket: "debate-app-2305f.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "418618483372",
  appId: "1:418618483372:web:89740de5372f5756ee3509",
  measurementId: "G-06DX6TELJD"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

I'm not planning on using the same `firebaseConfig` later, so it's fine. This is only for learning.

I've followed so many tutorials and none of them worked. I just wanted to store the information in the database under the discord username they gave me.

Comment: Do you see any relevant logs or errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're importing a *really* old version of Firebase. This works for me with the latest SDKs:

```
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
ref.set({
  name: "Hello world",
  email: "user@acme.com",
  position: 42,
  type: "open"
});
```

For a working example (against your database), see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/firebase-rtdb-add-data?file=index.js